# Create incrementing number field in Cognito Form

Tags: cognito-forms

Is there a way to have forms create an ongoing numbering field. I want to have my forms numbered automatically when they are filled in by a user.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

All form entries in [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com) are assigned an entry number, which automatically increases and is never reused.  This entry number can be included on the confirmation page (Insert Field, Entry - Number) as well as email notifications.  You can also reference the entry number in calculations to produce your own unique numbering scheme--just keep in mind that the entry number will not be assigned until the entry is submitted.

You can include the entry number on the confirmation page or email notifications:

[image]

You can use the entry number in calculations:

[image]