# Using Entry.Number in a calculation

Tags: cognito-forms

I'm not a programmer.

I need to generate unique voucher codes in Cognito Forms.

They need to include the (integer)Entry.Number + 10,000 as a 5 character string. E.g. if the (unique) serial Entry.Number is "13" I need to create a string "10013".

I'm not sure if Entry.Number is a numeric or string but I have a numeric integer field: `EntryNumber=Int32.Parse(Entry.Number)+10000`

and text field: `VoucherCode=SomeString+EntryNumber`

However the VoucherCode is always empty.

I know that that Entry.Number is only generated when the form is submitted but even if I put VoucherCode in the confirmation message, it still comes out empty.

[Create incrementing number field in Cognito Form](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/82296/create-incrementing-number-field-in-cognito-form) suggests that you CAN use Entry.Number in calculations.

If this isn't at all possible I need another mechanism to generate a unique 5 character string for inclusion into each voucher number.

Answer (score 1):

To include a unique ID number on your form confirmation page:

1. Add a Calculation field to your form labelled Voucher Code (or something similar).
2. Set the calculation to the following expression:

> =(Int32.Parse(Entry.Number) + 10000).ToString("D")

3. Insert the Voucher Code field into your form confirmation message.